# Spinnaker: configuring app health-check via Eureka

Tags: spinnaker

I am using Spinnaker and AWS to deploy services and I'd like to configure the health-check for an app. My app (a SpringBoot one) provides its own healthcheck endpoint and it registers itself with Eureka for service discovery. The service itself has no load balancer configured in Spinnaker (Eureka takes that responsibility).

This comment https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/180#issuecomment-64054004 hints that Eureka can be a healthCheck provider for an app:

> We currently have three healthCheckProviders. AWS, ELB, and Eureka.

. However, I couldn't find any documentation how to enable this.

Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a working setup with the below configuration. I have not tried the region placeholder, but according to Github, it will work correctly.

```
eureka:
  provider:
    enabled: true
    accounts:
      - name: myaccount
        regions:
          - us-west-2
        readOnlyUrl: "http://myeurekahost:8080/eureka"
```

See https://github.com/spinnaker/clouddriver/blob/master/clouddriver-eureka/src/main/groovy/com/netflix/spinnaker/clouddriver/eureka/EurekaProviderConfiguration.groovy#L61

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Dalton. This seems to be following the DNS-based setup of Eureka (https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Deploying-Eureka-Servers-in-EC2) and thus it make sense to do a dynamic replacement of the {{region}} based on what the config defines.
However, we are using service URLs and so there's no one URL to use but instead, several EIPs. This doesn't seem to be supported by looking at the sources.
Secondly, if I understand the mechanics correctly, Spinnaker will register itself with Eureka and derive health information for registered services from there. Is this correct?

Comment: Dalton's answer is correct with the addition that I had to create a Load Balancer and configure it with Route53.

Comment: Note that we updated the readme to be a little bit more explicit about this - https://github.com/spinnaker/clouddriver/tree/master/clouddriver-eureka